# Write either csv output OR parquet output, controlled via a configuration setting

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like my program to write output files either in csv or parquet format and the decision to use either of the format should be controlled via a configuration.

I could use something like this below.

```
// I would probably read opType via a JSON or XML.
val opType = "csv"

// Write output based on appropriate opType
optype match {
  case "csv" =>
    df.write.csv("/some/output/location")
  case "parquet" =>
    df.write.parquet("/some/output/location")
  case _ =>
    df.write.csv("/some/output/location/")
}
```

**Question:** Is there a better way to handle this scenario? Is there anyway I could use the string value of `opType` to call the appropriate function call whether `parquet` or `csv` ?

Any help or pointers are appreciated.

Comment: Scala (thankfully) doesn't support runtime evaluation of expressions. Even if it did, it wouldn't be better than this. The linear logic here is straight forward, clean and easy to understand. Why do you not like this ?

Comment: @sinanspd, Its not that I don't like it - Just wanted to know out of curiosity if it would be possible to further compact my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create Enum of possible file Types and make sure enum notations should follow spark **source fileType** keywords (i.e csv,parquet,orc,json,text etc)

Then you can do simply like this

```
df.write.format(optype).save(opPath)
```

Note: **Enum is used only for type checking and making sure input is not some incorrect or garbled value**.